# Vuejs - Grab items passed to component template

Tags: vue.js

So I have my markup looking like this:

```
<slider>
    <img src="{{ gallery_image('HM722_Silver_Creek_9978.jpg', 'full') }}" alt="HM722 Silver Creek" style="margin-top:-15%;" />
    <img src="{{ gallery_image('HM722_Silver_Creek_9978.jpg', 'full') }}" alt="HM722 Silver Creek" style="margin-top:-15%;" />
    <img src="{{ gallery_image('HM722_Silver_Creek_9978.jpg', 'full') }}" alt="HM722 Silver Creek" style="margin-top:-15%;" />
    <img src="{{ gallery_image('HM722_Silver_Creek_9978.jpg', 'full') }}" alt="HM722 Silver Creek" style="margin-top:-15%;" />
</slider>
```

It's using the slider component which you can see below:

```
var Slider = Vue.component('slider', {
    template: '#homepage-slideshow',

    replace: true,

    data: {
        current: 1,
        speed: 1000,
        margin: 0,
        slideLength: 4
    },

    props: {
        sliderWidth: 800,
        slideWidth: 800,
        height: 500,
        dataSlide: 1
    },

    ready: function() {
        this.sliderWidth = screen.width * 4;
        this.slideWidth = screen.width;
        this.height = screen.height;

        console.log( this.img );
    },

    methods: {
        thumbnailClick: function(e) {
            var slide = $(e.target).data('slide');
            var index = $('.slide').index( $('#' + slide) );
            this.current = index + 1;

            this.margin = this.slideWidth * (index);

            this.animateSlides();
        },

        animateSlides: function() {
            var self = this;

            $('.slides').animate({
                'margin-left': '-' + self.margin
            }, self.speed, function() {
                if( self.current === self.slideLength )
                {
                    self.current = 1;
                    $('.slides').css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The methods are still a mess so disregard those, but I want to try and do a v-repeat of the img tags being passed in since those will be looped through with a @foreach functionality. So there won't always be a definite 4.. The data attribute has a slideLength of 4 and the template has 4 areas, but what I REALLY want is to loop through whatever images are passed into the template.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: I seemed to have gotten past this by passing a prop to the component like so BUT I'm not sure how to loop through them still...:

`<slider img-count="4">`
And then accessing it with `this.imgCount` in my component. I don't know why I didn't think of this before!

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have gotten past this by passing a prop to the component like so:

```
<slider img-count="4">
```

And then accessing it with `this.imgCount` in my component. I don't know why I didn't think of this before!

Then in your component template after setting `this.count = this.imgCount` in your ready method:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="homepage-slideshow">
    <div class="slides" style="width:@{{ sliderWidth }}px">
        <article v-repeat="count" id="slide@{{ $index }}" class="slide" style="width:@{{ slideWidth }}px;height:@{{ height }}px">
            <content select="img:nth-of-type(@{{ $index + 1 }})"></content>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper container">
            <img v-repeat="count" src="/img/thumbnail.png" data-slide="slide@{{ $index }}" v-on="click: thumbnailClick" style="height:@{{ thumbnailHeight }}px" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```